# UITableView throws NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, uikit

After using `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` to remove a row from a table, I received an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` with the following text:

> Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections
>   contained in the table view after the update (1) must be equal to the
>   number of sections contained in the table view before the update (1),
>   plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted,
>   1 deleted).

The exception refers to the number of **sections** removed, but the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method is supposed to delete **rows**. As far as I can tell, the number of sections should be unaffected. How could this happen? What could cause the table to think that I want to remove rows?

The full line of code that causes the error is:

```
[self.contentTable
 deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:0]]
 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
```

Answer (score 0):

I did just manage to fix this. Turns out the cause of the confusion is an unhelpful error message.

My mistake was that I was trying to remove the wrong row (14 rows in my table, and I was trying to remove row 2147483647 - not coincidentally, this is the value of NSNotFound). Apparently, trying to remove this row yields an exception message concerning the number of sections in the table.